XDG environment variables message from flatpak update
I started getting this message lately at the end of my update script, after the part that updates flatpak packages:
      flatpak updates ...

Looking for updates…


        ID                         Branch     Op     Remote      Download
 1. [✓] com.visualstudio.code      stable     u      flathub     102.5 MB / 108.4 MB

Updating… ████████████████████ 100%  7.3 MB/s  00:00
Note that '/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share' is not in the search path
set by the XDG_DATA_HOME and XDG_DATA_DIRS
environment variables, so applications may not
be able to find it until you set them. The
directories currently searched are:

- /root/.local/share
        ID                         Branch     Op     Remote      Download
 1. [✓] com.visualstudio.code      stable     u      flathub     102.5 MB / 108.4 MB

Updates complete.

The thing is that when I look for these env variables in any file like .bashrc or profile on either /home/user or /etc I can't see any assignment to them.
Only XDG_DATA_DIRS shows up when a list of env variables is made on the user CLI:
$ env
. . . .
. . . .
. . . .
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/home/sandbar/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1001
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
. . . .
. . . .

Doing an env command on the root account only yield the XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP variable.
The allegedly missing path from these env vars, i.e. /var/lib/flatpak/exports/share, is clearly present in the XDG_DATA_DIRS value.
Should I set both these env vars in the /etc directory in say .bashrc or profile ?

What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
